# python: passing multiple parameters for Popen command

Tags: python, parameter-passing, popen

I have spent multiple hours trying to figure out how to pass multiple parameters to python script which is supposed to be executed by subprocess.Popen without any luck.

**Script:**

```
command = ['/usr/bin/python', '/tmp/script.py mcl=NULL mtp=data mnm=DS4INST \
          mno=NULL mse=NULL mce=cll01'] 

result = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, \
         stderr = subprocess.PIPE)

out, err = result.communicate()

print out, err
```

**I receive following error message:**

```
python: can't open file '/tmp/script.py mcl=NULL mtp=data mnm=DS4INST mno=NULL \
mse=NULL mce=cll01': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

However, when I execute script directly from shell

```
/usr/bin/python /tmp/script.py mcl=NULL mtp=data mnm=DS4INST mno=NULL \
mse=NULL mce=cll01
```

I receive desired output and error message isn't generated.

Please advise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
command = ['/usr/bin/python', '/tmp/script.py', 'mcl=NULL', 'mtp=data', 'mnm=DS4INST', 'mno=NULL' 'mse=NULL', 'mce=cll01']
```

In your code, the second element of `command` is considered as one single argument and interpreted as:

```
/usr/bin/python "/tmp/script.py mcl=NULL mtp=data mnm=DS4INST mno=NULL mse=NULL mce=cll01"
```

so just like a long filename with spaces.

You have to split the arguments into separate elements of the `command` list.

Comment: this one, for some reason executes script.py with each parameter separately

Comment: @m1k3y02 - I would then try a compromise: `['/usr/bin/python', '/tmp/script.py', 'mcl=NULL mtp=data …']`

Comment: it works, but sys.argv recognizes all parameters as one, so there is additional parsing required which I can handle. Thanks a lot.